# Passar e declarar parâmetro (matriz) em Polymer

Tags: polymer

eu preciso passar o seguinte prametro pra um elemento polymer:

```
[
  ["id", "nome",     "idade"],
  [1,    "matheus",  16],
  [2,    "cristian", 16],
  [3,    "pedro",    10],
  [4,    "henrique", 10]
]
```

como eu declaro essa variável (uma matrix) no campo propertie?

Answer (score 0):

Porque não utiliza um Array de objetos?

Ex:

```
Polymer({

  is: 'hello',

  properties: {
    users: Array
  },

  ready: function() {

    this.users = [
       {id: 1, nome: 'Mateus', idade: 16},
       {id: 2, nome: 'Cristian', idade: 16},
       {id: 3, nome: 'Pedro', idade: 16}
    ];

  }

});
```

Para acessar cada um dos usuários você pode iterar o `this.users`.

Ex:

```
this.users.forEach(function(user){
  console.log(user.id, user.nome, user.idade);
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.